# Write a simple list into a new CSV file

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

I'm new in python and I would like to know **how could I write a new CSV file** which contains a simple list. Then I will use this file in an Excel Worksheet.

---

**My ENTIRE code:**

```
import csv
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sock = urllib.urlopen("http://www.fatm.com.es/Datos_Equipo.asp?Cod=03CA0007")
htmlSource = sock.read()
sock.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)

form = soup.find("form", {'id': "FORM1"})
table = form.find("table")

entidad = [item.text.strip() for item in table.find_all('td')]

valores = [item.get('value') for item in form.find_all('input')]

lista = entidad

i = 0
x = 1

while i <=10:


    lista.insert(i+x, valores[i])
    i += 1
    x += 1

print lista

w = csv.writer(file(r'C:\Python27\yo.csv','wb'),dialect='excel')
w.writerows(lista)
```

---

```
lista = [u'Club', 
         u'CLUB TENIS DE MESA PORTUENSE',
         u'Nombre Equipo',
         u'C.T.M. PORTUENSE',
         u'Telefono fijo',
         u'630970055',
         u'Telefono Movil',
         u'630970055',
         u'E_Mail',
         u'M.LOPEZ_70@HOTMAIL.COM',
         u'Local de Juego',
         u'INSTITUTO MAR DE CADIZ',
         u'Categoria',
         u'DIVISION HONOR ANDALUZA',
         u'Grupo',
         u'GRUPO 9',
         u'Delegado',
         u'SANCHEZ SANTANO, JOSE MARIA',
         u'*Dias de Juego',
         u'SABADO',
         u'*Hora de Juego',
         u'17:00']
```

**My results:** an empty CSV file.  :(

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Off-topic: The built-in `file` is removed in Python 3. You should use `open` when you want to open a file.

Comment: can you tell us what you have in lista? it would greatly help if you can write a simple scipt reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am using 2.7.3 and no error shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import csv 

lista = [u'Club',
         u'CLUB TENIS DE MESA PORTUENSE',
         u'Nombre Equipo',
         u'C.T.M. PORTUENSE',
         u'Telefono fijo',
         u'630970055',
         u'Telefono Movil',
         u'630970055', u'E_Mail', u'M.LOPEZ_70@HOTMAIL.COM', u'Local de Juego', u'INSTITUTO MAR DE CADIZ', u'Categoria', u'DIVISION HONOR ANDALUZA', u'Grupo', u'GRUPO 9', u'Delegado', u'SANCHEZ SANTANO, JOSE MARIA', u'*Dias de Juego', u'SABADO', u'*Hora de Juego', u'17:00']

header = []
row = []
for i, val in enumerate(lista):
    if i%2==0:
        header.append(val)
    else:
        row.append(val)

out = open('file.csv', 'w')

w = csv.writer(out, dialect='excel')
w.writerow(header)
w.writerow(row)
out.close()
```

As a follow up side question. What I would do in your place is to create one list for your column names, like:

```
header = ['col_name1', 'col_name2', ... ]
```

and a list of lists for the values like:

```
values = [
   [row1_val1, row1_val2, ...],
   [row2_val1, row2_val2, ...],
   ...
]
```

Then you can do:

```
w.writerow(header)
for row in values:
    w.writerow(row)
```

Check the doc of the csv module, there might be a way to write all rows in one go. I've never used it myself.

Comment: Many thanks! Now, I will try to put this data in colomns and rows respectively... I hope I will figure out.

Comment: My pleasure :-) note that the rows are already defined in your structure. but it could help to split the column definition and the row values in your script. you would have one list for the column definition, and a list of lists for all rows. good luck!

Comment: It should be: 2 columns and 11rows --> Row1:[lista[0],lista[1]]. Row2[lista[2],lista[3]] ....  any ideas??? Thanks!!

Comment: I'll check! Thanks @Colin !!